How to implement a dynamic termination logic for TimeFolder solver
I have customized the TimeFold employee scheduling sample source. The default setting quarkus.timefold.solver.termination.spent-limit=30s is currently used which is 30 seconds for the schedule to prepare. But I have to implement a terminator, like if there is no 1% score improvement for 30 seconds. Then solver will terminate, otherwise it will continue the calculation.
Would anyone can give a guideline, on how to do it?

Take a look at unimprovedTimeSpend termination in the documentation. It does exactly what you need.
